# How should I reason when I have to choose between a class, struct and enum in Swift?

Tags: swift

Since classes, structs and enums all has constructors, properties and computed properties, how should I reason when choosing between them?

Comment: WWDC 2015 video [Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-414/) walks through the rationale of value types (e.g. struct) vs reference types (e.g. class).

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/119881/enums-structs-and-classes-in-swift

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ChristopheD's and Jack Wu's answers are good, but I feel they don't touch on enums, or miss their importance. Swift enums are (meant to be) a full implementation of algebraic data types. Classes and structs are traditionally used to model data in object-oriented languages, but enums are usually limited to being used as a convenient way to limit the value of a variable to a limited number of possibilities. E.g. (C++):

```
enum MaritalStatus { Unmarried, Married, Divorced, WidowedOrWidowered };
MaritalStatus m = Unmarried;
```

Swift enums can do the above but they can do a lot more. Of course the Language Guide has a pretty good [barcode modelling example](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_189) but the best example I know of that really drives home the point of modelling data with algebraic data types is Scott Wlaschin's presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/ScottWlaschin/ddd-with-fsharptypesystemlondonndc2013

You would probably benefit from going through the whole presentation but really to 'get' the point all you need to see is slide 60 where he shows how to model a 'payment method' in a typical line-of-business app.

The examples in the presentation are in F# but F# isn't *that* far off from Swift and you can pretty easily map between them. E.g., the payment methods enum in Swift would look like:

```
enum PaymentMethod {
    case cash // No extra data needed.
    case cheque(Int) // Cheque #.
    case card(CardType, CardNumber) // 2 pieces of extra data.
}
```

The point of the above is that each order's payment method can be only one of the above three methods. Anything else will not be allowed by the compiler. This is a very succinct alternative to building entire class hierarchies to model these almost trivial things.

The presentation really takes off from there and the best part is Swift can do almost everything that F# can in terms of data modelling, using optional types, etc.

Comment: Talk your way, any example about "discriminated unions, tagged unions, or variants" is good for demonstrating enum

Answer (score 17):

Besides the advice on the practical usage of class, struct and enum, here is the comparison that clarifies the abilities among them [Swift Classes, Structs, Enums, and Tuples compared](http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/swift-classes-structs-enums-and-tuples-compared/)

[image]

Comment: **enums can also take methods.** From Apple docs:"Enumerations in Swift are first-class types in their own right. They adopt many features traditionally supported only by classes, such as computed properties to provide additional information about the enumeration’s current value, and instance methods to provide functionality related to the values the enumeration represents. Enumerations can also define initializers to provide an initial case value; can be extended to expand their functionality beyond their original implementation; and can conform to protocols to provide standard functionality"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question in my case: When I create a custom model `(EX: UserModel(have: userId, username...))`  , Should I use Struct or Class?

Answer (score 9):

For starters, Classes are pass-by-reference and Structs are pass-by-copy.

`enums` are still a special type to specify, well, enumerations. They should be used just like before.

In general, the choice of Class vs Structs shouldn't be much different than before. Classes are still fit for larger/complex objects and Structs are good for small, isolated model objects. The fact that structs have protocols and such now should just serve to simplify your code and make it more efficient.

Comment: "Classes are pass-by-reference" No. Swift is always pass-by-value with parameters that are not marked `inout`, just like Java is always pass-by-value. Objects (instances of classes) are not values and cannot be "passed"; instead, you can only manipulate objects through pointers to objects. Structs are values. All types are passed by value when the parameter is not `inout`.

Comment: @newacct Great! Thanks for clarifying. This does not change anything in the answer though as, like you said, Objects are always passed by copying a pointer and effectively always "pass by reference"

Comment: Really not interested in arguing semantics here, but I should point out that Apple's wording is precisely “classes are passed by reference”. However the parameter/reference is passed by value, naturally.

Comment: I would also add that classes can inherit, structs can't.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's quite a refined discussion! I like the thoughts expressed here: [http://www.swift-studies.com/blog/2014/7/1/struct-enum-or-class](https://web.archive.org/web/20170307081203/http://www.swift-studies.com/blog/2014/7/1/struct-enum-or-class)

There's quite a lot of details, and their recommendations. I've copied their summary here, but it's a whole article

- **enums** are initialised by one of a finite number of cases, are
  completely defined by their case, and should always be valid
  instances of that case when instantiated
- **structs** should be used when
  there is not a finite number of valid instances (e.g. enum cases) and
  the struct also does not form a complete definition of an object, but
  rather an attribute of an object
- A **class** completely defines a primary
  actor in your object model, both its attributes and its interactions.

Answer (score 5):

[Structures have memberwise initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_94) (class instances do not receive a default memberwise initializer)

> All structures have an automatically-generated memberwise initializer,
>   which you can use to initialize the member properties of new structure
>   instances. Initial values for the properties of the new instance can
>   be passed to the memberwise initializer by name:

```
let vga = Resolution(width: 640, height: 480)
```

which makes perfect sense since they are value types (and thus `immutable`).

Enumerations are value types too. Classes are reference types. No real surprises here.

Comment: Swift structs are mutable, if you want them to be.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you would make use of structures over classes when the data you are defining is relatively simple, you don’t need to worry about referencing, or you don’t need to inherit another data structure’s properties and methods.

If you have data that should not be changed after initialization we can ensure that at compile time when using structs.

Use classes for situations where you know that the identity of the object is going to be important. In other words, use classes where you want multiple regions of code to be pointing at the very same instance of the the object.

Use structs for situations where you know that the value of the object matters. In other words, structs are great for situations where it doesn’t matter if two different regions of code are referring to the very same instance of to copy of the instance

If you need to share mutable state between parts of you program you should use a class.

If you need inheritance or you know you want to pass references to an object around, use a class.

Answer (score 4):

The most important difference between classes and other named types (structs/enums) is:

Structs cannot be subclasses (or substructs, so to speak) of anything. Nor can they be subclassed themselves. Inheritance is completely out of picture with structs. Same goes for enums.